# Nasm preprocessor - Address parameter via variable

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, nasm, preprocessor

I need to write a lot of `push` instructions that push different characters. I'd like to use a macro for that. This is what I've done so far:

```
%macro push_multi 1-*       ; Accept between 1 and ∞ arguments
    %assign i 1
    %rep %0                 ; %0 is number of arguments
        push %{i}
        %assign i i+1
    %endrep
%endmacro

push_multi 'a', 'b', 'c'    ; push 'a' then push 'b' then push 'c'
```

But the result with `nasm -E` is:

```
push %i
push %i
push %i
```

I want this:

```
push 'a'
push 'b'
push 'c'
```

How can I address the nth argument of a macro with a variable created with `assign`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `%rotate 1` you can rotate the macro argument list to the left by 1 element. This effectively places the next element in the list at the beginning. The first element in the list can always be referenced as `%1`. Putting this in a `%rep %0` loop will allow you to iterate through all elements in the macro argument list. The [*NASM* documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.3.8) for `%rotate` says this:

> %rotate is invoked with a single numeric argument (which may be an expression). The macro parameters are rotated to the left by that many places. If the argument to %rotate is negative, the macro parameters are rotated to the right.

In your case this should work:

```
%macro push_multi 1-*       ; Accept 1 or more arguments
    %rep %0                 ; %0 is number of arguments pass to macro
        push %1
        %rotate 1           ; Rotate to the next argument in the list
    %endrep
%endmacro
```

If you want to do the list in reverse you can rotate in the opposite direction with `-1` and by doing the `%rotate` first:

```
%macro push_multi 1-*       ; Accept 1 or more arguments
    %rep %0                 ; %0 is number of arguments pass to macro
        %rotate -1          ; Rotate to the prev argument in the list
                            ; If at beginning of list it wraps to end of list 
        push %1
    %endrep
%endmacro
```